# <div> element: How can i get my div text to be as it is while resizing

Tags: html, css

I have created this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9SnYL/) for my question.

In this particular fiddle when we resize the window the div elements change themselves accordingly as they should. But i want that not to happen. Using `{white-space: nowrap;}` don't seems to be a good option. little help will be appreciated. thank you.

```
<body>
  <p>This is a paragraph with no specified margins. i am writing stuffs to just make things long so as to provide a better understanding of my question.</p>
  <p class="margin">This is a paragraph with specified margins. i am writing stuffs to just make things long so as to provide a better understanding of my question. Press the "restore down" button present before "close button" or resize the window. It will change it shape according to CSS. I want that not happen. it should appear as it is while restoring or resizing.</p>
  <p align="center"> In short i want a responsive "div" elements. </p>
</body>
```

I need the div elements to be fixed, they should not change themselves while resizing. Thank you.

Comment: What specifically are you looking for? Justified text? Fixed widths on your div elements? Be specific.

Comment: I need the div elements to be fixed, they should not change themselves while resizing.

Comment: Is this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/9SnYL/2/ ??

Comment: Well your asking for responsive div elements, but fixed div's would not be responsive, and we also would need to know what fixed width you want. Why do you need them fixed? I'm not sure I understand exactly what your intending the final product to be. Tell me more about what your going for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set body width fix to solve this problem,

```
body{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:400px;
}
```

#### Check this <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9SnYL/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am understanding properly, but one idea would be to nest a fixed width div (done with width = 200px here, change as necessary) which holds your text inside of the main div / window:

```
<div id="Resizable">
    <div id="TextHolder" style="width:200px">
        <p>Your text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you need to set fixed width to your p elements.

```
p{
   width: 600px;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
}
```

or you just set the body width to be fixed. eg.

```
body{
  width: 600px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can use `min-width` or `max-width`

```
body{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    min-width:400px;
    max-width:500px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9SnYL/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set body width as user1153551 said in previous answer or you can set the width or your p element...

```
p
{
background-color:yellow;
width:400px;
}
```

Here is [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tanvir0604/9SnYL/4/)